# Ansible extract substring from stdout line causes empty string

Tags: regex, docker, ansible, yaml

**What i want to achieve:**

Get the list of running docker services on a specific node in ansible.

**How I tried to achieve this:**

```
---
- name: echo text (this will later be docker stack ps SERVICE instead of echo)
  shell: echo 'SomePrefix_value1.1\nSomePrefix_value2.1'
  register: result

- name: Print values
  debug: 
    msg: '{{ item | regex_search(regexp) }}'
  with_items: result.stdout_lines
  vars:
   regexp: 'SomePrefix_([^\.]+)'
```

In a first shot I just wanted to provide some example output and print out the desired values. But when I run those tasks I get just an empty String printed out.

`TASK [test-list : Print values] *****************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": ""
}`

I tried to set regexp to `'.*'` to verify that the problem is in the regexp end the task is successfully with this regexp and it prints the following:

`TASK [test-list : Print values] *****************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "result.stdout_lines"
}`

I thought it has something to do with escaping and therefore I printed out the value of regexp and got the following output:

`TASK [test-list : Print regexp] *****************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=None) => {
    "regexp": "SomePrefix_([^\\.]+)"
}`

I was wondering about the second `\` in the regexp, but after reading a bit it turned out that this is just in the debug output.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. On https://regex101.com my regex works fine. Can anybody give me a hint?

**Solved by the question that is marked as duplication**

I had to adapt with_items to be with_items: '{{ result.stdout_lines }}'

Comment: Besides the simple mistake with bare variables, you should use `msg` not `var` in the `debug`.

Comment: updated my question. Uses msg now.

Comment: You edited your comment multiple times ;) I read it and tried it. Works! Thank you :)